# git unable add device file?

Tags: linux, git

is git unable to commit a device file? Under Linux system.

For example:

```
git clone blah@blah.com:/blah.git
cd blah 
sudo cp -af /dev/ttyS0 .
git add .
git commit
```

git msg:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

`ls -ashl` result:

```
   0 crw-rw----  1 c2h2 c2h2 4, 64 Jun 24 14:23 ttyS0
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Git will not track device files at all (currently). Here's a comment from `dir.c`, [read_directory_recursive](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2141c474d0dd7cddf224780644e64bc7fa493f07/dir.c#L1209) (v1.7.8.5) function which is used when you do `git add .`:

```
 * Read a directory tree. We currently ignore anything but
 * directories, regular files and symlinks. That's because git
 * doesn't handle them at all yet. Maybe that will change some
 * day.
```

Git tracks contents, not files. So trying to make it track device files doesn't really fit - they don't really have content in a traditional sense.

An approach that would work is to create a script that creates/"installs" the device files your application/project needs (including fifos or whatever else you might need). Git can track that very effectively, and it's a handy form to have that in for an installer (or for other people using your tree).